# How to get all photos for a perticular user irrespective of date

Tags: instagram

How to get all posted photos in Instagram for a perticular user irrespective of date? 
In my case Instagram media API returns 20 photos only.

API I used is:
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/User-ID/media/recent/?client_id=CLIENT-ID

Thanks for your kind help.

Sanjeev Dutta

Answer (score 0):

Yes I found the way..using MAX_ID we can get the next bunch of photos store MAX_ID in local variable and call API recursively to get next set of photos..might be helpful to others..

Comment: Also note you can use next_url (if it exists) to paginate, see http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/ 'Pagination' section.